# Mapping SQLAlchemy object from dict automatically

Tags: json, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new with **Flask** and **SQLALchemy**.

I got a **User** instance `user`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    avatar = db.Column(db.String(64))
    ...
```

and i got a **json** `user_json`:

```
{
    'uname': 'John',
    'avatar': 'http://example/john.jpg',
    ...
}
```

I want to each filed of `user` will automatically update from the `json`.

And this is what i have tried:

```
for key, value in user_json.items():
    if key in self.__table__.columns:
        self[key] = value
```

And, obviously, it does't work. :(